# Html.BeginForm with route id parameter and get parameter on submit?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a method like this in my mvc project:

```
[Route("Categories/{categoryId}")]
public ActionResult List(SearchQueryCommand searchQuery) {
    //Stuff
    return View();

}
```

So this method is called like: `'www.myweb.com/Categories/212'`

But i have a dropdownlist with a form that sorts this query and send it back again to the server to get the sorted results.
I have this in my razor view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { categoryId = Model.CategoryId }))
{
                <div>
                    <small>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Order, "sort by")</small>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Order, Model.ProductSortByOptions, new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
                    <button class="nojs" type="submit">ok</button>
                </div>
}
```

My problem is that i dont know how to format my code to have in my url something like: `'www.myweb.com/Categories/213?Order=MinPrice'`.

What are my options to perform this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution! and is not with `Html.BeginForm`

My code is like this:

```
<form action="@Url.Action()" method="get">
     <div>
        <small>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Order, "ordenar por")</small>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Order, Model.ProductSortByOptions, new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
        <button class="nojs" type="submit">ok</button>
     </div>
</form>
```

This always set my form action to: `{Categories}/{categoryId}` and because is a `GET`, the `Order` will be set as a query parameter like i wanted.

Comment: Just to clarify, this *can* be done with `Html.BeginForm`, you just have to fill in all the parameter before you get to the form method, i.e.: `Html.BeginForm("List", "YourController", new { categoryId = Model.CategoryId }, FormMethod.Get)`. Granted, I generally take the same path you did in scenarios like these, because it's a little less arduous, although you don't need the `Url.Action()` bit: `action=""` works just as well.

Comment: It doesn't work in that way... because it generates an url like: `'www.myweb.com/YourController/List?categoryId=123'` and that URL wont work with my Route configuration on my method: `[Route("List/{categoryId")]`

Comment: If you're using attribute routing, you should comment out or remove the default route in `RouteConfig.cs`. Then, it will work.

Answer (score 2):

The method of your form needs to be a `GET`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { categoryId = Model.CategoryId }, FormMethod.Get))
```

This way, when the form is submitted, all of the form fields will be added to the querystring in the URL.

To post to specific action method, you will need to specify them in the `BeginForm` definition. I'm not too familiar with attribute-based route definition but one of these should work:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("List", "Categories", new { categoryId = Model.CategoryId }, FormMethod.Get))
```

Or

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Categories", new { categoryId = Model.CategoryId }, FormMethod.Get))
```

Comment: Yes... but this code will be like this on the url: 'www.mypage.com/Category/Categories?categoryId=231&Order=MinPrice' and that's not what i'm looking

Comment: The first mentioned method overload `BeginForm(object routeValues, FormMethod method)` does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

I route params in beginform POST method with RedirectToRoute, this generates a 302 http response, but i dont know other method.

in routeconfig

```
routes.MapRoute(
           name: "list",
           url: "{bti}-e-{bop}-e-{blo}-e-{bzo}-e-{bpr}-e-{bha}-e-{bor}",
           defaults: new { controller = "home", action = "list", bpr = UrlParameter.Optional, bha = UrlParameter.Optional, bor = UrlParameter.Optional }
           );
```

action get:

```
public ActionResult li(int activepage = 0,  Buscador bu = null)
    {
    your code...
    return View(model);
    }
```

action post:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult li(int activepage = 0,Buscador bu = null)
    {
     ..my code to format values...
     ..send values below that interest me routing.. 
     return RedirectToRoute("list", new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary { { "bti", bu.bti }, { "bop", bu.bop }, { "blo", bu.blo }, { "bzo", bu.bzo }, { "bpr", bu.bpr }, { "bha", bu.bha }, { "bor", bu.bor } });
    }
```

this work ok for me.

my english in very bad. sorry

Answer (score 1):

You need to add method GET to the form tag

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MethodName", "YourController",FormMethod.Get))
```

{
    ...
}

Then your Form tag will generate GET request and all params from form will be in URL query string.